# Alamofire parameters from textfield

Tags: swift, alamofire

```
@IBAction func login(sender: UIButton) {
        let parameters = [
            "username": usernameTextField?.text,
            "password": passwordTextField?.text
        ]


        Alamofire.request(.POST, "http://192.168.1.107:8080/api/v1/user/login", parameters: parameters, encoding: .JSON)
            .validate()
            .responseJSON { response in
                switch response.result {
                case .Success(let JSON):
                    print("Validation Successful")
                    if (JSON["status"] as! String != "Success") {
                        self.popup("Invalid Account", message: "Please check your username and password and try again")
                    }
                case .Failure(let error):
                    print(error)
                }
        }

    }
```

The parameters worked fine when I have the username and password hardcoded inside the dictionary. But when I changed it to a textfield, Im getting the error that says `Cannot convert value of type [String: String?] to [String: Anyobject]?`

How can I make the parameters anyobject so it would be accepted?

Answer (score 0):

**The error message is showing the there is optional type in params.**

just unwrap the values before using it if you are creating textfield at run time.
if not creating at runtime simply use it like

```
let parameters = [
        "username": usernameTextField.text,
        "password": passwordTextField.text
    ]
```